# Why is GDI+ linear gradient wrapping?

Tags: gdi+

I'm using a `Gdiplus::LinearGradientBrush` to draw a shadow effect for my document. It works well, but on the right hand side of my document the effect sometimes wraps around part way through the draw area. This only happens in a certain range as I scroll horizontally. For most of the scroll range, everything works fine. For the other sides of the document, everything works fine. As I scroll in the effected range, I can see the gradient wrap point gets stuck. I can scroll the rest of the document/background, but the gradient wrap point is stuck on a certain pixel of my screen.

```
graphics.SetPixelOffsetMode(Gdiplus::PixelOffsetModeHalf); //Gdiplus::Graphics
Gdiplus::Rect shadow(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y + cornerRadius, shadowWidth, vSideLength);
Gdiplus::LinearGradientBrush brush(shadow, alpha1, alpha2, 180.f);
brush.SetBlendBellShape(1);
graphics.FillRectangle(&brush, shadow);
```

What could cause this effect? I can post images if needed to better describe the problem.

Edit: images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTPU4.jpg). The gradient wrap point is fixed to a pixel in my window somehow, and the wrap point doesn't move as I scroll.

Comment: pictures would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a driver bug for my AMD 6xxx series video card. The Windows VGA driver did not exhibit this bug. The current AMD video drivers as of 10/2015 still have the bug. The workaround is to use multiple-of-16 width gradients.